# Cross Domain Google Analytics Showing Multiple Users

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I'm using analytics to track clicks and views, though due to the awkward setup (with iframes too) there's between 2 and 4 domains being used.  I want to track each of them like they are one site.

I know you can set the linker to create links that transfer the cookie data from one domain to the other.

My problem:  It's more likely that each of the domains that will loaded will be linked to from elsewhere, not within the site, so the linker will not work in the normal way.   If I view both pages at one, it records me as two users as there's two cookies created.

The links that will take them to each of the possible urls I cannot control, so can't add a linker to.

Does anyone know how get analytics to show two domains on one account so that it doesnt count as two users?

This is the code I currently have (had a fair few versions)

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Thank you!!

ADDED:

Sorry it would be a little like this:

Website 1 - Main website  www.mywebsite.com

Website 2 - Blog site  www.blogs.com/myblog

These are two entirely separate websites, and you may get to either one independantly and not just links between.

With linking, you can allow links between to keep the same cookie, so it registers as one user within the same tracking code covering both sites.

What I would like is for it to register as one user when you hit the sites independently.

The setup doesn’t matter too much, so long as it’s using the same tracking code so that I can track clicks and views for both sites in one place…

I hope that makes sense…

Comment: If you're setup is indeed awkward, then you're probably not going to find a one-size-fits-all solution. You need to be more specific about your setup if you actually want someone to be able to help.

Comment: reply added above.... thanks

Comment: In this line `ga('linker:autoLink', ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']);` are you using URLs or are you using domains? You should show your actual code instead of paraphrasing because that could be where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Phil..  The code on each page is identical to that above, I haven't put the URLs due to confidentiality of the client, but they are such as 'mywebsite.com', 'blog.myotherwebsite.com' etc. 

I however found a way round this as per my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working..  I couldn't get this working at all in the usual way, so instead I managed to use the User ID option.

Rather an generate a cookie based on the user / domain / browser etc as per default, you can set your own ID.  This then allows you to track the same user over multiple devices and browsers, so long as you can assign the same ID to the user...

I chose to base a user ID on the IP address of the user like this:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    var myIp = "";
    if(typeof response.ip!='undefined'){myIp="ID"+response.ip;myIp = myIp.replace(/\./g, "");}

    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
    ga('set', '&uid', myIp);
    ga('send', 'pageview');

}, "jsonp")
```

This seems to work perfectly so far, and tracks the same person on all sites even if they use more than one browser / mobile on the same network.   The only flaw being multiple users on the same IP address, which for this is unlikely and not worth the worry for the odd rare occurrence..

Comment: Same IP for different users is actually common - IPs are often dynamically assigned, so they change between visits and are reassigned to other people, and many people sit behind routers where their whole organization shares a public IP. Plus you violate the Google TOS (which might result in termination of your account) for the userID feature which stipulate that you must use the userID feature with the users permission only. Plus you probably violate EU law as IP adresses might be considered personally identifable information that must not be stored.

Comment: The original idea behind the userID feature is that the userId is supplied by a backend system for logged in users. If IP address was a reliable way to tell users apart there would be no need for a client id, or indeed a userID,  in GA in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Eike for the input there,  if it's indeed not allowed for you to collect IP addresses - The IP is actually changed when it's stored into something else that's unique, but is generated based on the IP - so I will check on that and change if so - thanks. 

Also, I know there should be no need to do it this way - ideally it would show the user as being the same person on both sites and so not have the need for this.  It may be an analytics flaw, or purely that i've got a really odd setup that means it just doesnt work that way - otherwise I wouldn't need a way around it..